# round bottomRight with byRoundingCorners not work

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make round corner for topLeft and rightBottom, the top round work well but leftBottom still rectangle,

I searched a lot I think it's overlap issue but don't know how to fix it, please any help?

P.S. it's work well just in IPhone Xs Max

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setRadius()

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setRadius()
    }
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        setRadius()
    }
    func setRadius()
    {
        let  cornerRadius = 18.0

        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners:  [.topLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

Comment: The layer's frame is probably not the same as the view's frame. Make sure you update the layer's frame when the view's frame changes.

Comment: how to update it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let your_Frame = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))//define your frame size you want
your_Frame.layer.cornerRadius = 25//deine the radius you want
your_Frame.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
view.addSubview(your_Frame)
```

Comment: it's not same what i want , first i'm using custom class , and the most important for me is just to round .topLeft, .bottomRight corner , i've edit my code but still have issue take alook plz